# singularity run or execute command as the same as docker run

Tags: docker, singularity-container

I am working under a university's HPC system, which has only `singularity` installed and without `docker`. I want to run an already `singularity`-pulled docker image (julia_adfem_v1.sif).  The original command for the docker environment is `docker run -ti kailaix/adcme` . What's it for `singularity`?

I have tried something like `singularity exec ./julia_adfem_v1.sif kailaix/adcme` but not sucessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, there are two different images

1. julia_adfem_v1.sif (an image that is already there locally)
2. kailaix/adcme (an image from docker hub)

Let me talk about case 1:

Note: `julia_adfem_v1.sif` is a container file.

To **run**:

```
singularity run julia_adfem_v1.sif
```

To **exec** with some command:

```
singularity exec julia_adfem_v1.sif echo "It's working!"
```

---

Let me talk about case 2:

Note: `kailaix/adcme` is a docker hub image file.

To **run**:

```
singularity run docker://kailaix/adcme
```

To **exec** with some command:

```
singularity exec docker://kailaix/adcme echo "It's working"
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. It is now quite clear for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a container from the docker registry, you can use the following:

```
singularity run docker://kailaix/adcme
```

If you want to exec something on the container, you can use:

```
singularity exec docker://kailaix/adcme echo "test"
```